# Application.ontime not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this line of Application.Ontime:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "'RefreshWorkbook'"
```

to re-call my sub declared using:

```
Public Sub RefreshWorkbook()
```

5 seconds later, but it does not work. Is there something I am doing wrong? The subroutine is in the "thisworkbook" module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Now + TimeValue(time) to schedule something to be run when a specific amount of time (counting from now) has elapsed. Use TimeValue(time) to schedule something to be run a specific time.